# How to run Docker to listen on a specific port to integrate with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, boot2docker, dockerpy

I am trying to use `Jenkins Docker plugin`. Unfortunately I am not able to run Docker on RHEL to listen on a specific port yet.

I know I have to add:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

But in my RHEL installation dont find the `/etc/init/docker.conf` file.

So which file to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` like below.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -H fd:// -H 0.0.0.0:4243 -d
```